# Webpack dev server recompiles when hot but bundle doesn't actually change

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack for testing the output of a code generation library I'm writing: https://github.com/Neone-character-creator/app-generator/blob/master/project-template/webpack.config.js

The library copies files into a new directory and webpack serves them.

The end result will package the web app as a Java jar injected into a server, the front end will select the content it should display and embeds it inside an iframe. I am trying to simulate this, where I display demo.html, which contains an iframe that loads `sheet.html`, which loads `app.bundle.js`.

When the dev server is running and I change some files and re-invoke the library, the updated files are moved into place and in the console I can see that webpack performs a recompilation.

However, when I look at the compiled bundle, it is actually unchanged, even though the source files the bundle is derived from is different. I have to restart the server for the bundle to actually update.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    "mode": "development",
    "entry": "./src/main/resources/scripts/app.js",
    "output" : {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main/resources/scripts/"),
        filename: "app.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/src/main/resources"
    },
    devServer:{
        before: function(app, server){
            app.use("/templates/sheet.html", function(req, res) {
                const resourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/main/resources" + req.baseUrl);
                res.sendFile(resourcePath);
            });
            app.use(/\/scripts\/.*/, function(req, res) {
                const resourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/main/resources" + req.baseUrl);
                res.sendFile(resourcePath);
            });
        },
        contentBase: __dirname,
        port: 9999,
        hot: true,
        index: "demo.html",
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "demo.html",
        }
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "use": {
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "presets": [
                            "@babel/env",
                            "@babel/react"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Adding the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` to the webpack config and the `--hot` and `--inline` flags to the dev-server command does not work.

Comment: can you show your config?

Comment: @bobharley Added

Comment: Possible to setup a minimal git repo to explore the issue?

Comment: I believe webpack dev server serves compiled bundles from memory and other static assets or forwarded endpoints from where it's configured to. You won't see them change on the file system. The one you see that isn't changing was probably left over from a previous non-dev-server build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the following happens here:

I think, you start your dev server by [`npm start`](https://github.com/Neone-character-creator/app-generator/blob/master/project-template/package.json#L7) script resided in your repository package.json. This script does an initial full build with `webpack-cli` which outputs the bundle to your target directory. If the build succeeds, it watches all your sources files with help of `webpack-dev-server` command recompiling the bundle if sources change.

Problem is: `webpack-cli` will write to disk, `webpack-dev-server` per default will build the bundle [in memory](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server) amongst others for performance reasons during development:

> webpack-dev-server doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory and serves them as if they were real files mounted at the server's root path.

So effectively you write once to disk and then have a stale bundle in the file system, while dev server compiles the changes and serves them via in memory.

If I understand you correctly, you are reliant on the compiled bundle output to be written as a file, so you can further package the bundle/webapp as a Java jar for a server. If you want to still use webpack-dev-server to make use of the web server and the ability to use live reloading, there is a [`devServer.writeToDisk`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-) option, which can be enabled (default: false):

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true
  }
};
```

As an alternative, you could utilize Webpack's [watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#choosing-a-development-tool) to just recompile, if one of the files is updated, so that you do not have to build manually.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  //...
  "watch": "webpack --watch"
}
```

Comment: Webpack is not necessary for the final output of the library, it is an intermediate testing tool. Webpack keeping the hot recompiled files in memory answers the question of why the on-disk file is not updated, but doesn't explain why the content the dev server serves doesn't change.

Comment: Adding the writeToDisk to the devServer config did it! You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: No worries! Actually I wanted to give it a second try with your concrete repo, but glad that this already did the trick for you! Sometimes webpack can be ....

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku small addendum to your first comment: The reason, why the dev server did not serve updated content without the option `devServer.writeToDisk: true` is that you have configured your middleware in `webpack.config.js` ("before"-property) to resolve to *file system paths* for `/templates/sheet.html` & Co. In order to point to content from webpack-dev-server, the served source references in the html files must be the in-memory resource paths which are prefixed with the `publicPath` property. Or you could try to redirect to these URLs in the middleware.

Comment: memo (in case it gets deleted from repo): `npm start` is `npm i && webpack-cli && webpack-dev-server --open`